# Initial rendering has a flicker when dark mode enabled on SSR

Tags: material-ui, server-side-rendering

When SSR is used and using global styles on _document.tsx, dark mode is not used on initial(first) loading.
For example, the root of  tag doesn't have data-theme itself, but after initial loading it has data-theme="dark" as a attribute.

What I wanna know is, how do you set data-theme="dark" if user has enabled it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [dark mode SSR flickering](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/27651) is a known issue, so you're not alone in your frustration. The current solution is to use [CSS theme variables](https://mui.com/material-ui/experimental-api/css-theme-variables/overview/), which make it possible to inject a theme into your app's stylesheet at *build time* to apply the user's selected settings *before* the whole app is rendered. This feature is currently considered experimental but should be stable in Material UI v6.

Comment: I'd really like to say thank you for the information! This is still experiment at the time, but worth to use it!